# Content of fillable pdf form does not show up in LaTex

Tags: pdf, pdfpages

I have a problem importing a pdf into LaTeX using includepdf. More precisely, I would like to include a .pdf file that has already been filled and signed but what happens is that only the blank form is displayed (albeit with my signature at the end, very strangely). How to make sure that the filled content is displayed correctly? Could it be a problem with the .pdf file?

Below is a MWE which doesn't work for me.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages=-]{Filled form.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried flattening the filled form? E.g., with the `pdftk` program, `pdftk in.pdf output out.pdf flatten`

Comment: That worked indeed, thanks Thérèse!